# Can We Replace App delegate old core data methods in place of new core data xcode 8.3 method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I've created a new project Using Xcode 8.3.2 with core data which have different core data methods from core data methods created using xcode 7.

It's running on iOS 10 but gives error when try to run same on iOS 9.

New Core data methods like

```
 @synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;

- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"ieMalayalam"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                     NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    abort();
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    return _persistentContainer;
}

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Can we replace old core data methods for supporting ios 9 & 10 both.?????
Please Help

Comment: No.You can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Fixed it by replacing the old core data method (xcode 7) with new one(xcode 8) .**

The app runs on ios 9 & 10 both .
Thanks for you to all your vision.

Answer (score 1):

These methods are more of a template to give you an example on how to implement Core Data. Your first job after you created a project that includes core data is to restructure the whole system. You should move the whole logic far away from application delegate to begin with.

So once you have a nice system to operate with core data you can copy the same system to another project and over time your system may be greatly improved and extended, maybe even ready for open sourcing it.

If you are not up to all of that maintenance you can search for some open sources. I believe there are quite a few coca pods for instance. I believe Magical Record is used quite a lot.